# jQuery get the result back from php in json format

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a `$.post` how can I get the result back from php?

```
$.post("sql/customer_save.php",{ what: "edit",customer_no: $customer_no});
```

php respond back

```
echo json_encode(array("customer_id"=>$customer_id,"customer_no"=>$customer_no));
```

what should I put on $.post in order to get the result back??

Answer (score 4):

```
$.post("sql/customer_save.php",{ what: "edit",customer_no: $customer_no},function(resp)
{
   //resp is your response
   //You can try
    console.log(resp);
    console.log(resp["customer_id"]); //get the value of customer_id
    console.log(resp["customer_no"]); //get the value of customer_no
},"json");
```

or

You can also use

```
 $.post("sql/customer_save.php",{ what: "edit",customer_no: $customer_no},function(resp)
    {
       //resp is your response
       //You can try
        var data = $.parseJSON(resp);
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data["customer_id"]); //get the value of customer_id
        console.log(data["customer_no"]); //get the value of customer_no
    });
```

Comment: Amirali: If you're wondering what was different... a `"json"` parameter was added in the `$.post` call. This tells jQuery to expect a JSON formed response.

Comment: Is it any way that I can get each field separately?? like customer_id, customer_no??

Comment: Access them this way, resp.customer_id and resp.customer_no

Comment: I prefer using resp["customer_id"] and resp["customer_no"].
I forgot the reason :P

Comment: The resp variable in the callback function of your post request is a json object referring to the encoded array. That's why you can access in ways like we mentioned.